# How can I configure vscode so that it recognize my buildout imports?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plone, pylint, buildout

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, and I can't get pylint to stop throwing "unable to import" errors, or autocomplete to recognize my imports such as :

```
from collective.transmogrifier.interfaces import ISection
from collective.transmogrifier.interfaces import ISectionBlueprint
from zope.annotation.interfaces import IAnnotations
from zope.interface import classProvides
from zope.interface import implements
```

I used PyCharm before, for which all I needed was to mark "parts/omelette" directory as source, for any plone/buildout project, and it worked fine.

In vscode, I've tried to add workspace settings as such :

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "parts/omelette"
    ],
```

Or even copying my whole bin/instance egg paths and adding them to autocomplete extra paths, without success.

I'm sure some people in the Plone community have tried vscode before ! I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this buildout recipe can serve your purpose.
[collective.recipe.vscode](https://pypi.org/project/collective.recipe.vscode/)

Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: In the recipe I had to enable `generate-envfile = true`, otherwise the imports were not found and autocompletion were broken.